# Estás versus Eres: meanings in "you are a noun + adjective"

Tags: verbos, cópulas, presente-indicativo

Please can someone confirm if this understanding is correct?

Both of the following sentences are correct. The distinction is that the first sentence grammatically says "at this moment you are a naughty girl" whereas the second is says "you are a naughty kind of girl".

> 1. Tú estás una chica traviesa
> 2. Tú eres una chica traviesa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`The distinction is that the first sentence grammatically says "at this moment you are a naughty girl"` This is **incorrect**.

What you mean happens in this example: you see the girl all "dolled up" in her prom dress or something like that. Then, you could say

> [Tú] Estás preciosa [con ese vestido] <sub>You **look** beautiful in that dress/ the dress makes you beautiful</sub>
>
> [Tú] Eres preciosa <sub>You **are** beautiful - and the dress just remarks that</sub>

In your particular case

> Tú eres una chica traviesa

indeed means "you are naughty", like in "that's inherent to you", but

> Tú **estás** una chica traviesa

is plain wrong (it's a "word by word" translation, not a translation of the intended meaning). You would say

> Tú **estás** traviesa hoy/esta mañana/en este momento

like

> Tú **estás** preciosa con ese vestido/con el pelo recogido/esta mañana

You are translating literally "you are a naughty girl today" and that doesn't work in Spanish with "estar" because you'll say that someone "está traviesa/hermosa" but **you don't say that someone "está una chica"**.

So you can say that someone "es una chica + adj", because that's inherent to them or a quality or a personality trait.

You cannot say someone "está una chica + adj", because "ella **es** una chica", and you could add that "ella **es** una chica hermosa, traviesa o alta, que puede **estar** más o menos -insert adjective here- en un momento dado".